# Trying to set a date field to barcode

Tags: excel, barcode, barcode-scanner, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I am attempting to add a barcode on a spreadsheet that i am using. the problem is when i try and convert the date field, it comes out as a excel datetime type.

```
="*"&A5&"*"
```

A5 is my date field, and this is what the barcode looks like before i switch it to the font.

```
 *40763*
```

does anyone have any ideas on how i can make that so I can barcode the date field?

I'm using Excel 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For day/month/year:

```
="*" & DAY(A5) & "/" & MONTH(A5) & "/" & YEAR(A5) & "*"
```